# assessing significance of difference between two groups using difference sample sizes

Tags: statistical-significance, sample-size

I am looking into assessing the effect of a condition. I have a population of several individuals that are not affected by this condition and a smaller proportion that is. Observations of a single variable are made at several points in time. I would like to assess how early (in time) I can find a significant difference between groups. The idea is that at any time of observation, I would use all the available data to make the assessment. My current idea is to run a test for the difference between groups (let’s say t-test for sake of argument), at several points in time, using all data available until then.
But somehow this doesn’t feel right (using the same data multiple times?) and get the feeling there must be an elegant way of addressing this problem. Any comments or suggestions?